# Dockerized React app on Node - How to copy files?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

So I have these env variables defining the SSL files and I want to copy them to my container, somehow they are not copied by default even if they are in my project folder.

> You specified SSL_CRT_FILE in your env, but the file "/usr/src/app/server.cert" can't be found

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

MAINTAINER Kuba Wasilewski <jakub.wasilewski@sprint.pl>
 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
COPY package*.json ./
 
RUN npm install
 
ARG REACT_APP_API_URL

ENV REACT_APP_API_URL ${REACT_APP_API_URL}

COPY . .

ENV HTTPS=true
# these are the files that are not copied by default
ENV SSL_CRT_FILE=server.cert
ENV SSL_KEY_FILE=server.key
 
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: *How to copy files?* with `COPY`, have you created the certs?

Comment: server.cert and server.key are existed in your project?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified the working directory as `/usr/src/app`, the ***COPY*** commands should copy any project files to that location.

```js
FROM node:10

MAINTAINER Kuba Wasilewski <jakub.wasilewski@sprint.pl>
 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app
 
RUN npm install
 
ARG REACT_APP_API_URL

ENV REACT_APP_API_URL ${REACT_APP_API_URL}

COPY . /usr/src/app

ENV HTTPS=true
# these are the files that are not copied by default
ENV SSL_CRT_FILE=server.cert
ENV SSL_KEY_FILE=server.key
 
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```